# Grid Detection with Scipy

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision, transformation

I want to identify points in an image which are arranged in a regular 4 x 5 grid:

[image: raw image]

With dynamic thresholding and some opening and closing, I have labeled the image:

[image: labelled image]

Extracting the centroids from those gives me a set of points. I now want to fit a 4 x 5 grid to this image, and then transform the image to make the grid square and flat.

Can anyone suggest how I might go about this? I looked at the Hough transform but that's for lines rather than points.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you want implement a camera calibration. There are many libs which can do that - unfortunately I cannot recommend one due to my lacking experience. http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html might be a possible solution